# How do I have more than one type of out of stock on woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock

I am using "[How to add new stock status to products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61798283/11987538)" to change the text of availability on WooCommerce for a course website that I am making on behalf of my client.

```php
 // Availability text
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    switch( $product->stock_status ) {
        case 'coming_soon':
            $availability = __( 'Coming soon', 'woocommerce' ); 
        break;
        case 'dtbc':
            $availability = __( 'Dates to be confirmed', 'woocommerce' ); 
        break;
    }
    return $availability; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability_text', 10, 2 );

// Availability class
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability_class( $class, $product ) {
    switch( $product->stock_status ) {
        case 'coming_soon':
            $class = 'coming_soon'; 
        break;
        case 'dtbc':
            $class = 'dtbc'; 
        break;
    }

    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_class', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability_class', 10, 2 );
```

---

I am looking for help to turn the ability to purchase off on the two extra classes that I am adding so that they are effectively different variations of out of stock. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, I understand however I am looking for advice to find the file that contains the different drop-down options so that I can go from there if that makes sense. Many thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried that and it is working well however I am wondering if it is possible to turn off purchasing for certain categories if that makes sense?  Thank you for your help so far :-)

Comment: I have now updated my question, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have done a lot of research into this and cannot find anything about it. I am new to this community so don't know how it works. I am just a 17-year-old looking for a little help with it. As previously said, any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

For example, I created a new status called "**Sold Out**",
And **returns** false when the **is_in_stock** function is called.

```
// Add new stock status options
function filter_woocommerce_product_stock_status_options( $status ) {
    // Add new statuses
    $status['sold'] = 'Sold Out';
    return $status;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_stock_status_options', 'filter_woocommerce_product_stock_status_options', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    // Get stock status
    switch( $product->get_stock_status() ) {
        case 'sold':
            $availability = 'Sold Out';
            break;
    }

    return $availability;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability_text', 10, 2 );

// Availability CSS class
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability_class( $class, $product ) {
    // Get stock status
    switch( $product->get_stock_status() ) {
        case 'sold':
            $class = 'sold';
            break;
    }

    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_class', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability_class', 10, 2 );

// Set is_in_stock For Sold status
function filter_woocommerce_product_is_in_stock( $instock_this_get_stock_status, $instance ) {
    if($instance->stock_status == 'sold'){
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', 'filter_woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', 10, 2 );
```