# Display product stock status on single product pages in WooCommerce when price field is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm adding a new stock status in WooCommerce products. It has been done by the help of [How to add custom stock status to products in WooCommerce 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61798283/2297943) answer code.

But the problem is that when the price field of products is empty it doesn't show the status (front-end). but otherwise when the product has the price, it shows the status.

What can I do, to make the status be shown even if the price field is empty?

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself is. If you do not use that extra code, so a default product stock status is displayed for a product. **If the price is then empty, is the default product stock status still displayed?** if not, then this has nothing to do with the extra code but with standard behavior in WooCommerce, so you have to look for the solution in that direction

Comment: @7uc1f3r  it doesn't show stock status of the product at the default status with price being empty. what can I do for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will see that if the price is empty, besides not showing the product stock status, the price (the HTML code) for this will also not be displayed. Because the product is considered as not purchasable if the price is empty.

So in order to display the product stock status, you should make the product purchasable, if the price is empty. However, I do not believe this is your intention?

So instead of focusing on displaying the product stock status, it will be much simpler to display something else (HTML/text) where the price is normally displayed,
and that can be done by using the `woocommerce_empty_price_html` filter hook

1. So either you drop the whole idea of ​​the product stock status and simply use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_empty_price_html( $html, $product ) {
    // NOT true on a single product page, RETURN
    if ( ! is_product() ) return $html;
    
    // Add HTML
    $html = '<p>My text</p>';

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_empty_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

---

2. Or you build further on the product stock status and on that basis you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_empty_price_html( $html, $product ) {
    // NOT true on a single product page, RETURN
    if ( ! is_product() ) return $html;
    
    // Get stock status
    $product_stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();
    
    // Compare
    if ( $product_stock_status == 'MY CUSTOM STATUS' ) {
        // Add HTML
        $html = '<p>My text based on product stock status</p>';
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_empty_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

---

The only downside to this solution(s) is that your new HTML/text will not be displayed where you normally see the product stock status, but where the price is normally displayed.