# Adding colours to WooCommerce Stock Status

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, custom-code

I followed this Post([How to add custom stock status to products in WooCommerce 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796640/how-to-add-custom-stock-status-to-products-in-woocommerce-4))--- and I was able to add New WooCommerce Stock Status.

What remains is to add different colours to the stock status.

How can I do that?

Comment: in the answered code you linked, there is literally a section called `// Availability CSS class` - Apply CSS to those classes.

Comment: It worked on the backend, but it's not working on the Frontend